# FileInfoComparer not sorting correctly (on LastWriteTime)

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, directoryinfo

I have a simple (ASP.NET) web page  that lists files of a particular type in a folder and renders them in a ListView.

I've tried to sort them by descending LastWriteTime, that is, in reverse date order. However, although the sort process does change the order of the array, it doesn't sort it correctly. For example, one item with a LastWriteTime of `#6/3/2011 12:00:00` is top of the list, but another item with a LastWriteTime of `#12/16/2011 12:00:00` is halfway down the list after sorting.

Any ideas why?

Code:

```
        Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(AppSettings.Item("ContentDir")))
        Dim FileArrayList As New ArrayList(dirInfo.GetFiles("*.msg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))

        Dim SortDirections As New Dictionary(Of String, SqlClient.SortOrder)

        With FileArrayList
            .TrimToSize()
            .Sort(New FileInfoComparer(SqlClient.SortOrder.Descending, "LastWriteTime"))
        End With
```

FileInforComparer class:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection


Public Class FileInfoComparer
    Implements IComparer

    Private _sortOrder As System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder
    Private _sortColumn As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Constructs new Comparer object, using the supplied SortOrder and SortColumn parameters
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sortOrder">Defines the SortOrder for the comparison</param>
    ''' <param name="sortColumn">Defines which column is sorted</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(ByVal sortOrder As System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder, ByVal sortColumn As String)
        _sortOrder = sortOrder
        _sortColumn = sortColumn
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Defines the Sorting mechanism for FileInfo objects
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="x">First FileInfo object to compare</param>
    ''' <param name="y">Second FileInfo object to compare</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Overridable Overloads Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare

        Dim oX_PI As PropertyInfo = CType(x, FileInfo).GetType.GetProperty(_sortColumn)
        Dim oY_PI As PropertyInfo = CType(y, FileInfo).GetType.GetProperty(_sortColumn)
        Dim Result As Int16 = oX_PI.GetValue(x, Nothing).CompareTo(oY_PI.GetValue(x, Nothing))

        'If DESC then reverse the result
        If _sortOrder = SqlClient.SortOrder.Descending Then Result = Result * -1

        Return Result

    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: `FileInfoComparer` isn't a standard class, I believe...

Comment: Aye, you are correct - posted in haste! I've updated the code snippet.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  If you have access to LINQ, why not just use its `Sort` method?

Comment: Mainly because I don't know LINQ! This is something knocked-up in a hurry a year or two ago, and I'm just trying to make a quick change. I'm using v4 of the Framework.

Comment: @cadrell0 - while I'd like to understand the solution to my current approach, I'm open to alternatives. Perhaps you might guide me as to how I would use LINQ instead?

Answer (score 3):

LastWriteTime may be returned as a string, which explains the sort order. the values are sorted as strings, not DateTime objects. parse the string to datetime and the sort order should be correct.

Comment: You might be right that I am not sorting by Date, but it certainly isn't sorting by text. I did consider this, but to be honest, I cant understand the sort criteria. Nevertheless, I'll look at modifying my code to specifically handle dates.

Comment: As far as I can tell `oX_PI.GetValue(x, Nothing)` returns a Date object. Does .ComppareTo not correctly compare Date objects?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses LINQ.  This was written in C# and [converted](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to VB, so hopefully this works.

```
Dim dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(AppSettings.Item("ContentDir")))
Dim fileList = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.msg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime)
```

The type of `fileList` will be `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`.  If you need it to be a a mutable list, rather than using an `ArrayList`, I would recommend using a `List<FileInfo>`, which can be done by adding `.ToList()` to then end, like so

```
Dim fileList = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.msg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).ToList()
```